# Cannot go back to previous windows from Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

As going back to Windows 8.1 from Windows 10 from my HP Envy laptop, I failed to see the go-back/recovery screen after reboot - Windows 10 keeps appearing again as a normal restart.

I cannot go back now even goggling about this topic will all link to `Go back setting` as snapshots below. I follow the screen but my Windows 10 keep restart as-is.

Do you have the same problem? How to workaround it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

"If options to go back and restore factory settings aren’t available, you can use installation media and a product key to install a previous version of Windows."

[Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/help-upgrade-windows-10)

Comment: Does that mean I will lost my installed softwares?